# i want to restrict user on typing number from 0 to 28 alone inspite of giving min and max value

Tags: html

In textbox of type number - restrict to number,
with min and max value - restrict from incrementing value,
but I want to disable user to type number, because when user types a number, they could give greater than max value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of guiding the user. If there is a max value to the field you could either state that in a label or you choose a number picker with only valid values instead of a free text field where everything can be entered. This is usually cleaner than allowing the user to enter out-of-range values, catching them and then returning an error.